# Excerpt of tag `operator` - incorrect definition?

Tags: discussion, tags

The following definition sounds incorrect to me:

> An operator is a processing unit that is invoked/executed on scene
>   data by the window manager.

Are operations only run on *scene data*? All of the 3D View and interface operators  change properties of Screen data, not Scene for instance. Even *blend(lib) data* wouldn't be quite right, as you can write operators that only report something and not change anything.

---

A user action starts by device input of the user and the window manager dispatches these and events and starts operations - so *by the window manager* is correct. However, this is very technical and rather an implementation detail than a useful information for the end-user.

Comment: You can always suggest an edit http://blender.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/74.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure how to describe it right... Maybe borrow some lines from http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Architecture/Operators ?

Comment: You're an active dev, up to you. ;)